# creating pthreads in loop and passing incremented arguments, threads are not using the correct argument values

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am creating a program that reads in a file of matrices.  I store these matrices in a struct with an array of structs containing an array of the matrix values (ex: matrixArray.array -> matrix.array). I then create multiple threads that calculate the product of each row for 2 matrices.  I have created a counter that is passed as an argument in pthread_create() that tells the thread which matrices to use, and which row in those matrices. I am printing out the results of this counter in the loop that calls pthread_create(), and the results I am getting are correct.  However, I am also printing the values inside the function pthread_create() calls, and the values don't always match.  It will skip some of the numbers, and will duplicate others.

Here is my main function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pthread_t * tid; /* the thread identifier */
    pthread_attr_t attr; /* set of attributes for the thread */
    int i; // Counter
    int aIndex; // Index of the current 'A' matrix being multiplied.
    int rows,cols;
    int array[2];

    // Check to make sure we have the correct number of arguments supplied
    // when running the program.
    if(argc < 1){
            printf("Error: You did not provide the correct number of arguments.\n\n");
            return 0;
    }

    // Read the file and create the matrices
    readFile();

    // Get the default attributes
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);

    // Initialize the mutex lock
    pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL);

    // Set the current set to be mutliplied to 1
    currentSet = 1;

    // Allocate size of tid array based on number of threads
    tid = malloc(threads * sizeof(pthread_t));

    // Create the threads.
    for(i = 0; i < threads; i++){
            pthread_mutex_lock(&lock); // Lock the global variable so no other threads can access it
                    aIndex = ((currentSet * 2) - 2);
                    array[0] = currentSet;
                    array[1] = mtx.array[aIndex].multRow;
          //pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock); // Unlock the global variable so other threads can access it.

          // This prints the values stored in array. Array is passed inside pthread_create
          // 0 is the set of matrices that are to be multiplied together, with each
          // set containing 2 matrices, an A matrix and a B matrix.  
          // 1 represents the row in the A matrix that should be multiplied with matrix B
          printf("0 = %i, 1 = %i aIndex = %i\n",array[0],array[1],aIndex);

            pthread_create(&tid[i], &attr, runner, array);

            // Increment currentSet when the current row evalutated
            // in the current set is equal to the total number of rows available.

          //pthread_mutex_lock(&lock); // Lock the global variable so no other threads can access it.
                    mtx.array[aIndex].multRow++;

                    if(mtx.array[aIndex].multRow == mtx.array[aIndex].rows){
                            currentSet++;
                    }
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock); // Unlock the global variable so other threads can access it.

    }

    // Wait for threads to finish
    for(i = 0; i < threads; i++){
            pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
    }

    // Print the matrices
    printMatrices();


    // Clean up the mutex when we are done with it.
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);

    exit(0);

} // End of main()
```

mtx is a matrixArray struct that contains an array of matrix structs defined as:

```
typedef struct matrix {
    int rows;
    int cols;
    volatile int multRow; // The "MULTIPLIED ROW" This is for determing which row the current thread needs to use for multiplication. This only applies for Matrix A in each set.
    int size;
    int set; // This is for which set the matrix belongs to.
    char letter; // This is for labeling the matrices A B and C
    int * array;
    unsigned int * threadID; // Array containing the thread ids that are used to create the result
} matrix;

typedef struct matrixArray {
    int size;
    matrix * array;
} matrixArray;
```

My runner function, which is the function that pthread_create calls, is defined as:

```
void *runner(void *param) {
    int * array = (int*)param;
    int pSet = array[0];
    int multRow = array[1];
    unsigned int threadID = (unsigned int)pthread_self();
printf("set = %i row = %i worker thread = %u\n",pSet,multRow,(unsigned int)pthread_self());
    // Do the matrix multiplication for a single row

    // The matrices are stored globally, so we do not need to pass that data.
    // However, we do want to pass in a reference to which matrices we want to
    // multiply.

    // The matrices we are dealing with are ((pSet * 2) - 2) and ((pSet * 2) - 1)
    // Need to create a new matrix C that will store the result of the matrix multiplication
    int rows, cols; // The dimensions of the matrix C.
    int aIndex, bIndex, cIndex; // The index of the matrices in the array.
    int i, r, c; // Counters
    int result; // This stores the result of the multiplication
    int aValueIndex, bValueIndex, cValueIndex; // These store the index of the value to be multiplied in each matrix

    aIndex = ((pSet * 2) - 2);
    bIndex = ((pSet * 2) - 1);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock); // Lock the global variables so no other thread can access it.
            rows = mtx.array[aIndex].rows;
            cols = mtx.array[bIndex].cols;

            // First we need to check if the matrix C for this set has been created.
            for(i = 0; i < mtxResults.size; i++){
                    if(mtxResults.array[i].set == pSet){
//printf("Found Set %i\n",i);
                            cIndex = i; // Store the index to this matrix
                            break;
                    }
            }

            // Now it is time to multiply the matrix row
            for (c = 0; c < cols; c++){
                    for (r = 0; r < mtx.array[bIndex].rows; r++){
                            // Need to calculate the location of the values we want to multiply
                            // Value in matrix A is going to be the current row 'r' from the 
                            // counter plus the current row being evaluated by this thread * the
                            // total number of columns of matrix A. 
                            // Value in matrix B is 'c' + (r * total number of columns in B)
                            // Multiply the values at those two locations and add them to the 
                            // running result.
                            //aValueIndex = r + (mtx.array[aIndex].multRow * mtx.array[aIndex].cols);
                            aValueIndex = r + (multRow * mtx.array[aIndex].cols);
                            bValueIndex = c + (r * mtx.array[bIndex].cols);
                            result = result + (mtx.array[aIndex].array[aValueIndex] * mtx.array[bIndex].array[bValueIndex]);
                    }
                    // Now place the value in the C matrix after calculating the location
                    // to place the value.
                    //cValueIndex = c + (mtx.array[aIndex].multRow * mtx.array[bIndex].cols);
                    cValueIndex = c + (multRow * mtx.array[bIndex].cols);
                    mtxResults.array[cIndex].array[cValueIndex] = result;

                    // Reset result
                    result = 0;
            }

            // Store the threadID in the result matrix
            mtxResults.array[cIndex].threadID[mtx.array[aIndex].multRow] = threadID;

      pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock); // Unlock the global variables so other threads can access it.

    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

The printf() statement 5 lines in to runner is where I am printing the values that are passed to the function, and they don't always match.  Here is some output for the program:

```
0 = 1, 1 = 0 aIndex = 0
0 = 1, 1 = 1 aIndex = 0
0 = 1, 1 = 2 aIndex = 0
0 = 2, 1 = 0 aIndex = 2
0 = 2, 1 = 1 aIndex = 2
0 = 2, 1 = 2 aIndex = 2
0 = 2, 1 = 3 aIndex = 2
0 = 3, 1 = 0 aIndex = 4
set = 3 row = 0 worker thread = 3913365824
0 = 3, 1 = 1 aIndex = 4
0 = 3, 1 = 2 aIndex = 4
0 = 3, 1 = 3 aIndex = 4
0 = 3, 1 = 4 aIndex = 4
0 = 4, 1 = 0 aIndex = 6
0 = 4, 1 = 1 aIndex = 6
0 = 4, 1 = 2 aIndex = 6
set = 4 row = 2 worker thread = 3923855680
set = 4 row = 2 worker thread = 3934345536
set = 4 row = 2 worker thread = 3944835392
set = 4 row = 2 worker thread = 3955325248
set = 4 row = 2 worker thread = 3965815104
set = 4 row = 2 worker thread = 3976304960
set = 4 row = 2 worker thread = 3986794816
set = 4 row = 2 worker thread = 3997284672
set = 4 row = 2 worker thread = 4007774528
set = 4 row = 2 worker thread = 4018264384
set = 4 row = 2 worker thread = 4028754240
set = 4 row = 2 worker thread = 4039244096
set = 4 row = 2 worker thread = 4049733952
set = 4 row = 2 worker thread = 4060223808
0 = 4, 1 = 3 aIndex = 6
0 = 4, 1 = 4 aIndex = 6
0 = 4, 1 = 5 aIndex = 6
0 = 4, 1 = 6 aIndex = 6
0 = 4, 1 = 7 aIndex = 6
0 = 4, 1 = 8 aIndex = 6
0 = 4, 1 = 9 aIndex = 6
set = 4 row = 9 worker thread = 4070713664
set = 4 row = 9 worker thread = 4081203520
set = 4 row = 9 worker thread = 4091693376
set = 4 row = 9 worker thread = 4102183232
set = 4 row = 9 worker thread = 4112673088
set = 4 row = 9 worker thread = 4123162944
set = 4 row = 9 worker thread = 4133652800
0 = 5, 1 = 0 aIndex = 8
0 = 5, 1 = 1 aIndex = 8
0 = 5, 1 = 2 aIndex = 8
0 = 5, 1 = 3 aIndex = 8
0 = 5, 1 = 4 aIndex = 8
0 = 5, 1 = 5 aIndex = 8
0 = 5, 1 = 6 aIndex = 8
set = 5 row = 6 worker thread = 4144142656
set = 5 row = 6 worker thread = 4154632512
set = 5 row = 6 worker thread = 4165122368
set = 5 row = 6 worker thread = 4175612224
set = 5 row = 6 worker thread = 4186102080
set = 5 row = 6 worker thread = 4196591936
set = 5 row = 6 worker thread = 4207081792
0 = 6, 1 = 0 aIndex = 10
0 = 6, 1 = 1 aIndex = 10
0 = 6, 1 = 2 aIndex = 10
0 = 6, 1 = 3 aIndex = 10
set = 6 row = 3 worker thread = 4217571648
set = 6 row = 3 worker thread = 4249041216
set = 6 row = 3 worker thread = 4238551360
set = 6 row = 3 worker thread = 4228061504
```

The lines that begin with 0 are the ones that are printed in the for loop in the main function. They are exactly what I expect them to be.  They are being passed to the runner function where they are being passed again, but as you can see, some of the values are skipped, while others are duplicated.  In the 2 different outputs, 0 = set and 1 = row, so there should have been one set/row pair matching each 0/1 pair.

I should also note that my program worked perfectly when not using threads, and also when only creating one thread at a time and waiting for it to finish before creating a new thread.

This is a homework assignment that is do in a few hours (I have been working on this for a week, and just got passed some other road blocks), so any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use a single array to pass values into multiple threads because every thread is reading the same array.

To make this work better create a struct with all of the data each thread needs. Then make an array of those structs, one array entry for each thread. Pass each thread a pointer to ONE of those structs.

That way each thread has access to its own information and will not read or write another thread's info.